# Solve for values which produce negative real Eigenvalues?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Given an n x n matrix "A", with one or more unknown parameters, I'd like to show a plot of which values produce stability (negative Eigenvalues).

For example, say you have a simple mass-spring-damper system by:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

A = {{0, 1}, {-k, -c}}

eigA = Eigenvalues[A]
```

Is it possible to generate a plot showing c values in terms of k, or vise-versa?
I've attempted methods such as

```
Solve[First[eigA]==0,k],
Solve[First[eigA]==0,k],
Reduce[First[eigA]<0 && eigA[[2]]<0,k],
```

etc. but these outputs nothing? What am I doing wrong?
Ultimately I'd like to have a color coded plot, showing areas of stability and instability, if this is possible in Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't exactly understand what you're asking for, but is this roughly what you are looking for?

```
A = {{0, 1}, {-k, -c}};
eigA = Eigenvalues[A];
RegionPlot[Min[eigA] < 0, {c, -4, 4}, {k, -2, 2}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"c", "k"}] // Quiet
```

[image]

As another amusing example of a two-parameter matrix stability diagram (where blue indicates stability, and red instability):

```
$A[k_, c_] := Eigenvalues[N@( {
      {1, 0, Sin[k]},
      {0, 1 + Sin[c], Cos[c k]},
      {Sin[k], Cos[c k], 1}
     } )];
Image[hue[Table[Min[$A[k, c]], {k, -4, 4, 0.01}, {c, -4, 4, 0.01}]], 
 ColorSpace -> Hue]
```

[image]

where

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {(1.0 Arg[-z] + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]), 
    Exp[1 - Max[Abs[z], 1]], Min[Abs[z], 1]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for, however picking some test values the region does not seem accurate? Such as k=1,c=1 is outside of the region but still provides negative Eigenvalues. Perhaps we must only specify the real part as negative?

Comment: @gKirkland: I'm not sure what you're talking about. $k=c=1$ produces eigenvalues which are the primitive third roots of unity, which are not negative, as the diagram correctly shows.

Comment: Hmmm... if k=c=1 then A={{0,1},{-1,-1,}}. Eigenvalues are {-0.5-0.866025 I,-0.5+0.866025 I} are they not?

Comment: @gKirkland: Yes. They are not negative. Are they supposed to be considered as stable because the real part is negative? If so, I can modify my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The imaginary part is not, corrrect, but looking for stability I'm only interested in the real part.
I changed to RegionPlot[Re[eigA[[1]]] < 0 && Re[eigA[[2]]] < 0,...] and this seems to be producing what I need. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gKirkland: What do you mean "the imaginary part is not correct?"

Comment: The imaginary part is not negative, which is okay as I'm only interesting in the real part (indicating stability) at this point. However, later I'll need to adjust the code to solve for Eigenvalues which lie within the unit circle. But I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.